# Symmetric tensor polynomials generated by power sums?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, tensors, symmetric-polynomials

For a (noncommutative) ring $R$, I will denote by $\langle r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle_{\mathrm{sym}}$ the set of elements $p$ of $R$ generated by the elements $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in R$, such that $p$ viewed as a "polynomial" $p(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ is invariant under permutations $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)\mapsto (r_{\pi(1)},\ldots,r_{\pi(n)})$, $\pi\in S_n$.

**Conjecture**: For a (free?) ring $R$, $\langle r_1,\ldots,r_n\rangle_{\mathrm{sym}}=\langle \sum_{i=1}^n r_i, \sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2,\ldots,\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^k,\ldots\rangle$.

In practice, I am only interested in the special case of tensors. Consider a set of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in V$ and the algebra $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\rangle$ of all tensors generated by them. Similarly one can define permutation-invariant tensors $\langle v_1,\ldots,v_n\rangle_{\mathrm{sym}}$ (note that this is *not* the same as symmetric tensors: for example $v_1\otimes v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_2\otimes v_1$ is permutation-invariant but not symmetric in the traditional sense).

I claim that all such permutation-invariant tensors can be expressed as linear combinations of terms that are tensor products of power-sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^{\otimes k}$.

For example, $v_1\otimes v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_2\otimes v_1=(v_1^{\otimes 2}+v_2^{\otimes 2})\otimes (v_1+v_2)-(v_1^{\otimes 3}+v_2^{\otimes 3})$.

I would like to find out whether such a theorem is known, or if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim happens to be correct for $n=2$, but is false for $n \geq 3$, as I show below.
For convenience, I omit the "tensor product" symbol in my computations ; you just need to remember that multiplication is not commutative in my notation.

Denote by $B$ your set of $n$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Recall that a pure tensor is a tensor of the form $b_1b_2\ldots b_k$ where each $b_i$ is in $B$.  In general, a tensor will not be pure but will be a linear combination of pure tensors. The action of $S_n$ on all tensors restricts to an action on pure tensors ; for a pure tensor $p$, denote by $Orb(p)$ the orbit of $p$ under this action (thus $Orb(p)$ is a finite set with cardinality dividing $|S_n|=n!$) and let $s(p)=\sum_{q\in Orb(p)}q$. Then, the $s(p)$ form a basis of the subspace of permutation-invariant tensors. The question is therefore whether every $s(p)$
is in your subspace defined by power sums (let us call this subspace $T$).

Let $p$ be a pure tensor, we can uniquely write $p=b_1^{e_1}b_2^{e_2}\ldots b_l^{e_l}$ where each $b_i$ is in $B$, $b_{i+1}\neq b_i$  ; we call $l$ the complexity of $p$. By extension, the complexity of a linear combination of pure tensors is the largest complexity of the component tensors.

For $n=2$, your claim is true because of

**Lemma.** Suppose $n=2$ and let $p=b_1^{e_1}b_2^{e_2}\ldots b_l^{e_l}$ as above, $q=b_1^{e_1}b_2^{e_2}\ldots b_{l-1}^{e_{l-1}}$ and $r=b_l^{e_l}$ (so that $p=qr$). Then $s(p)-s(q)s(r)$ has complexity $\lt l$.

**Proof of lemma.** Let $\tau=(1,2)$ be the unique non-identity element of $S_2$. Then $s(p)=p+\tau(p)$ for every $p$. Hence

$$s(p)-s(q)s(r)=(p+\tau(p))-(q+\tau(q))(r+\tau(r))=q\tau(r)+\tau(q)r=s(q\tau(r))$$

and $q\tau(r)=b_1^{e_1}b_2^{e_2}\ldots b_{l-1}^{e_{l-1}+e_l}$ has complexity $l-1$. QED

Once we have the lemma, it is easy to deduce that every $s(p)$ is in $T$ by induction on the complexity of $p$.

When $n\geq 3$ however, there is a dimension mismatch : for tensor products of three elements, the permutation-invariant subspace has dimension $5$ with basis
$s(v_1^3),s(v_1^2v_2),s(v_1v_2^2),s(v_1v_2v_1),s(v_1v_2v_3)$. The corresponding subspace of $T$ has dimension $4$ with basis $t_1^3,t_1t_2,t_2t_1,t_3$.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any known simple basis of generators of permutation-invariant noncommutative polynomials?

Comment: @level1807 The obvious choice is the $s(v_{i_1}v_{i_2}\ldots v_{i_r})$ where the sequence $i_1,\ldots,i_r$ satisfies the following condition : $i_1=1$ and for each $k>1$, $i_k$ is either an already used index (i.e. $i_k\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\}$ or else $i_k$ is the smallest positive integer not in $\{i_1,\ldots,i_{k-1}\}$.

Comment: yeah that’s obvious of course, I’m just wondering if there are stronger results that don’t include sums over permutation groups. Oh well.

Comment: might want to have a look at the theory of multisymmetric functions see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304727/a-generalization-of-newton-girard-identities/304763#304763